# date table with FilterWeek, FilterMonth and FilterYear ( (...) , -3, -2 , previous year, current year, next year, 1, 2, 3

Tags: sql, date, filter

I woul like to create a date table where there is a filter column included voor week, month and year

Name would be:
FilterWeek   --> ( (...) , -3, -2 , previous week, current week, next week, 1, 2, 3, (...) )
FilterMonth  --> ( (...) , -3, -2 , previous month, current month, next month, 1, 2, 3, (...) )
FilterYear   --> ( (...) , -3, -2 , previous year, current year, next year, 1, 2, 3, (...) )

I want to use these columns in PowerBI as a filter option.
I have seen it before, but cannot find examples of this code. I have not enough experience to build this yet.

Comment: Nobody knows the answer? :(